# How to compute the the basis of the Null space in Maple

Tags: maple

Can any one tell me how to find the basis for the Null space of a matrix A in Maple?
I mean, If A is any Matrix of real numbers, then I want to compute the basis of the subspace Null(A).
Thanks to every one who will can support me with the code.

Answer (score 2):

It is very easy. Let's have a matrix like $A$:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
  6 & 4 & 2\\
  3 & 2 & 1 \\
  0 &0 &0
\end{pmatrix}$$ Now you can call just:

```
  with(LinearAlgebra):
  NullSpace(A);
```

> $$\langle \begin{pmatrix}
>   2  \\
>   -3 \\
>   0 \\
>   1  
> \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
>   1  \\
>   -2 \\
>   1 \\
>   0  
> \end{pmatrix}\rangle$$

Comment: Helpful! To the rescue! $ \left(_++^+\right)$

Comment: Thanks Babak, but does the null space we get consider to be the basis itself?

Comment: @user50382: The final code gives us the vectors in which we can find the N.S. of a matrix. That's it. If we intend to do another jobs, please give me the details. I 'll try to do so for you. :)

Comment: Thanks again Babak. Well, I have a linear map A (any matrix) and y in a finite dimensional space, and I want to get x such that Ax=y, where A here could be invertible matrix or could be not. So could you help me for doing that?Thanks

Comment: @user50382: Sorry for the delay. Give me A and y, since without them we can't find x. I'll try to do that via MAPLE. :)

Answer (score 1):

In addition another answers;

[image]

$\color{red}{You ~can ~use ~this ~code ~for ~plot}$

[image]

Comment: Nice attempt. $+^+$

Comment: @Software:Hi.my pal want set a new weblog can you design this frame ?he will pay its cost.

Comment: @Maisam Hedyelloo i'm not a professional in design frame.
Just because I love doing it.